# PySpark merge three columns to make a struct

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new on PySpark and I'm facing a challenge to solve a problem. I need to merge three columns, but the value will depend on a fourth column:

For example, I have this kind of table:

| store | car | color | cylinder | options |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John's | Ferrari | [blue, red] | [1.6, 1.8, 2.0] | [0, 2] |

And I'd like to change to this format

| store | car_info |
| --- | --- |
| John's | {Ferrari: [blue, 2.0]} |

Where the color and cylinder will be based on the options column.

I've tried to use the create_map function but is not working.

```
CAR_DATA.select('*', create_map('car', array((col('color'), col('cylinder'))))).show(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution using `expr`:

```py
df = df.selectExpr("store", "map(car, array(color[options[0]], cylinder[options[1]])) car_info")

df.show(1, False)

# +------+------------------------+
# |store |car_info                |
# +------+------------------------+
# |John's|{Ferrari -> [blue, 2.0]}|
# +------+------------------------+
```